# Fire event through widgets flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-android

I'm trying to create a flutter widget containing a list of ElevatedButtons. These ElevatedButtons can be selected (when they are they change color).
I wish it were only possible to select one at a time, so when an ElevatedButton is fired, the others should turn off.
How can I do?

This is the parent widget that contains all the buttons widgets.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:netvideo/widget/recordingslot-button.dart';

class RecordingSlotContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  const RecordingSlotContainer({super.key});
  final int recording_slots = 5;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
              children: List.generate(recording_slots, (index) {
            return RecordingSlotButton();
          })),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This if the RecordingSlotButton widget ( the single button ):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RecordingSlotButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const RecordingSlotButton({super.key});

  @override
  State<RecordingSlotButton> createState() => _RecordingSlotButtonState();
}

class _RecordingSlotButtonState extends State<RecordingSlotButton> {
  bool is_selected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            backgroundColor: is_selected ? Colors.blue : Colors.red),
        onPressed: () => {
              setState(() {
                is_selected = !is_selected;
                print("$is_selected");
              })
            },
        child: Text(""));
  }
}
```

Use with TOGGLEBUTTON:

```
class _RecordingSlotContainerState extends State<RecordingSlotContainer> {
  late List<bool> _selections;
  late List<People> _list;

  final int recording_slots = 5;

  Future<List<People>> getList() async {
    _list = List.generate(recording_slots,
        (_) => People(name: "Test", surname: "Test", nickname: "test"));

    _selections = List.generate(recording_slots, (_) => false);

    return _list;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(children: [
          FutureBuilder(
              future: getList(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return snapshot.hasData
                    ? ToggleButtons(
                        direction: Axis.vertical,
                        isSelected: _selections,
                        fillColor: Color.fromARGB(150, 76, 175, 80),
                        selectedColor: Colors.black,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        onPressed: (int index) {
                          setState(() {
                            for (int i = 0; i < _selections.length; i++) {
                              _selections[i] = i == index;
                            }

                            print(_selections);
                          });
                        },
                        children: List.generate(
                          snapshot.data!.length,
                          (index) {
                            return RecordingSlotButton(snapshot.data![index]);
                          },
                        ),
                      )
                    : const Text("Loading..");
              })
        ])),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ToggleButtons rather than using ElevatedButtons for this usecase.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ToggleButtons-class.html

Comment: Thank you, it's working. I have only one problem, I wrote a futurebuilder to load me the list from a database, if I click on an element the list List <bool> _isselected works but the element doesn't change color.

Comment: I have edited the code in the first post

Comment: Change `selectedColor` to something else. In your code `selectedColor` and `color` both are `Colors.black`.

Comment: Changed but it's not working. If I remove the future builders goes green....

Comment: Change `isSelected: _selections` to `isSelected: snapshot.data`

Comment: or add setState around `_selections` in `getList`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249164/discussion-between-blacky99-and-tirth-patel).

Comment: Ok, I missing something. isSelected: snapshot.data give me an error because snapshot.data it's a List of Objects not List of boolean ( objects that is my list of toggle button), and setState around _selections in getList not solve the problem